# Custom Variables in event tracking , Google analytic

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

```
onclick ="_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Name',document.getElementById('Name').value),3]);"
```

I used the above code on an onclick event to pass the value of Name as custom variable

But Trying to use Custom  variable filter on Google Analytic Report, it looks like that value is not passed as custom variable and the filter return 0 result

some idea what wrong could be  ?

THe whole senario is like this

```
onclick="timeTracker._recordStartTime();"
onclick="timeTracker._recordEndTime();
                    timeTracker._track(pageTracker, 'Catagory','Action','Name  = '  + document.getElementById('Name').value);

                    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Name',document.getElementById('Name').value,3],['_trackPageview']);"
```

I needed the customer variable because I needed to pass additional values for filtering purpose

Answer (score 3):

Add a `['_trackPageview']` after you set a custom variable.

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Name','Test',3],['_trackPageview']);
```

> In certain cases this might not be possible, and you will need to set another _trackPageview() request after setting a custom variable. This is typically only necessary in those situations where the user triggers a session- or visit-level custom var, where it is not possible to bundle that method with a pageview, event, or ecommerce tracking call.

From `Recommended Practices` section on [Custom Variables in Google docs](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html). Scroll to bottom of page.

Comment: Thanks a lot that means , every time to track an event i need to add ['_trackPageview']. in my cased i have 6 on-click event which i want to track.

Comment: @Mark If you have that many, you could create a function to handle it that fires on the `onclick` event.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is ok except you are missing an opening bracket on your `getElementById`. But to test if GA is or isn't working as it should convert that field to something static and test. Then go dynamic.

```
onclick ="_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 
    1, 
    'Name',
    document.getElementById('Name').value) // missing a () here?
    ,3
]);"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Name','Test',3]); , tried like this ..still didnt work